# How would I compile / build this project?

Tags: build

I've been wanting to do some edits and build this project but I currently do not understand the 'Build Instructions'. I thought someone with more experience can show me the way. This is the project https://github.com/HouQiming/qpad

Answer (score 0):

It is mentioned in `Readme.md`

You need to be on Windows OS and have Visual Studio Installed.

Comment: I did read that and hasn't solved my problem. I am on Windows & I have Visual Studio, I need someone to elaborate.